# Can't access a certain page with HTMLUnit

Tags: load, html, htmlunit

I try to access a website with HTMLUnit, but it gives me a huge code of error, and can't even output the title of the webpage. 
My code can't move on from....

```
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.itba.edu.ar");
    System.out.println(page.getTitleText());
```

It does work on Google and other sites, but I can't manage to make it work for this one. I tried changing the browser versions but that didn't help either.

Huge error:

```
Exception in thread "main" ======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[687] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[ReferenceError]     
sourceName=[script in http://www.itba.edu.ar/ from (687, 52) to (692, 15)] message=  
[ReferenceError: "addEventListener" is not defined. (script in http://www.itba.edu.ar/  
from (687, 52) to (692, 15)#687)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "addEventListener" is    
not defined. (script in http://www.itba.edu.ar/ from (687, 52) to (692, 15)#687)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:555)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:530)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:979)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:337)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:415)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:260)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:276)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:676)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:635)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3074)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2041)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:918)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:892)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:241)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:187)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:434)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:309)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:374)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:359)
at Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError:    
"addEventListener" is not defined. (script in http://www.itba.edu.ar/ from (687, 52) to  (692, 15)#687)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3603)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3587)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3657)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getNameFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2118)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1321)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:275)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:546)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:654)
... 32 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError:   "addEventListener" is not defined. (script in http://www.itba.edu.ar/ from (687, 52) to (692, 15)#687)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3603)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3587)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3657)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getNameFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2118)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1321)
at script(script in http://www.itba.edu.ar/ from (687, 52) to (692, 15):687)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:275)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:546)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:654)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:555)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:530)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:979)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:337)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:415)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:260)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:276)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:676)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:635)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3074)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2041)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:918)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:892)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:241)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:187)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:434)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:309)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:374)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:359)
at Main.main(Main.java:23)
======= EXCEPTION END ========
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Don't post the error as a link. Post it here, as text, in a code block.

Comment: there, I was able to post it